# PHP extract ID from a string

Tags: php, regex

E.g: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,  [ID: 123] Suspendisse [blahsh 68] condimentu

How would I get 123?

I have the first part where I check the character position:

```
$pos = strrpos($l, "ID: ");
if ($pos === false) {
    $id = 123;
}
```

Comment: I am guessing I need to learn regular expressions. Can anybody recommend a good place to start/reference?

Comment: Is the ID always wrapped with square brackets?

Comment: @JohnMagnolia http://www.regular-expressions.info/ is the best place to start, though it is dense. It is a very comprehensive reference.

Comment: Yeah I have tried to pick it up but it just seem like there is no logic in the code and complete gobbledigook. Looks like

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is most easily handled with a regular expression.

```
$matches = array();
$pattern = '/^.*\[ID:\s+(\d+)\].*$/';
preg_match($pattern, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, [ID: 123] Suspendisse [blahsh 68] condimentu", $matches);


// Your number is in $matches[1]
Array
(
    [0] => Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, [ID: 123] Suspendisse [blahsh 68] condimentu
    [1] => 123
)
```

The pattern matches `[ID:` followed by any number of spaces  via `\s+`.  Then `(\d+)` captures the sequence of digits.  The `[]` brackets need to be escaped as `\[ \]` because they are meta-characters in the regular expression.

If you are interested in the rest of the expression:

- `^.*` is the start of the string and anything else following...
- `.*$` is anything else up to the end of the string after the matched section already explained above.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe like this if the string is always [ID:1234]

```
$str='Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, [ID: 123] Suspendisse [blahsh 68] condimentu';
preg_match_all("~\[ID:\s(.*?\d+)\]~",$str,$match);
echo $match[1][0];
```